# Put part of 3D-Model in another file

Tags: export, 3d-printing

I'm very new to blender and the most recent project I was working on was my first.
I wanted to model a headset stand for my self and then send the file to a friend, so he can print it.
Since I didn't know, he would need to have separate files for him to be able to print it, I just modelled it all in one file. So now my question is, if it's possible to take one part of my model and export it into another one.
I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

So if I know what you mean, this should work.

So I just quickly modeled this headphone stand (Sorry for it being terrible lol I spent like 5 seconds on it):

[image]

And in edit mode, you will need to press "P" and this menu will pop up:

[image]

There are 3 different options:

**Option 1 (Separate from "Selection"):**

This means that if I select a part of the shape in Edit Mode, I can bring those selected parts into another mesh.

For example, if I selected this:

[image]

I could press "P", and select "Selection", and it would turn into 2 different meshes:

[image]

**Option 2 (By material):**

This one is pretty easy to understand out of context. If you have a mesh with 2 different materials:

[image]

If I selected Separate by "Materials" the blue color would be separated from the Orange color.

**Option 3 (Separate from Loose Parts)**

If you have multiple meshes in edit mode, you can select "Seperate from "Loose Parts"" and it will separate the loose parts:

[image]

Let me know if this helps!